# Tengo una etiqueta HTML con cierre implícito o algo que no me fijo

Tags: html, html5, angular

Tengo este código HTML en angular, que me esta dando problemas con una etiqueta DIV, creo que es una etiqueta de cierre implícito o que no necesita cierre, pero NO la identifico. si ustedes pueden ver algo le agradezco la ayuda.

El código es:

```html
<br><br>
<div class="container py-1">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center col-sm-12">
      <h5>Experiencias Laborales </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 text-lg-start col-sm-12 text-sm-center">
      <button class="btn" *ngIf="estaLogueado()">
        <img id="iconEditar" src="../../assets/icons-svg/edit.svg" alt="iconsPencel" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#modalWord" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalWord">
      </button>
      <button class="btn" *ngIf="estaLogueado()">
        <img id="iconEditar" src="../../assets/icons-svg/add.svg" alt="iconsPencel" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#modalAdd" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalAdd">
      </button>
      <button class="btn" *ngIf="estaLogueado()">
        <img id="iconEditar" src="../../assets/icons-svg/delete.svg" alt="iconsPencel" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#modalDelete" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalDelete">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center py-3" *ngFor="let word of wordExperience">
    <div class="col-3 text-center">
      <img class="imagenWorkEducation" src="{{word.url_photo_business}}" alt="Imagen-empresa">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <h5> {{ word.name_business }} </h5>
      <h6> {{ word.job }} </h6>
      <h6> {{ word.duration }} </h6>
      <span> {{ word.chores }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- //////////// modal eliminar //////////////// -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Eliminar Experiencia Laboral</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3 align-items-center" *ngFor="let wordDelete of wordExperience">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre de la Empresa:</label><br>
            <strong>{{wordDelete.name_business}}</strong><br>
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">id: {{wordDelete.id_word}} 
              <button class="btn" *ngIf="estaLogueado()">
                <img id="iconEditar" src="../../assets/icons-svg/delete.svg" alt="iconsPencel"><a href="">Eliminar</a>
              </button><br>
            </label>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>   
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ////////////modal de agregar experiencia new//////////////// -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalAdd" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalAddLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar Experiencia Laboral</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre de la Empresa:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordAdd.name_business">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Cargo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordAdd.job">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Actividades o Roles:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea [(ngModel)]="wordAdd.chores">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Duración:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordAdd.duration">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Logo de la Empresa (url):</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordAdd.url_photo_business">
          </div>
          
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addDB()">Guardar Cambios</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /////////////modal editar/////////////// -->

<div class="modal" id="modalWord" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalWord" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Editar Experiencia Laboral</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let wordE of wordExperience">
                   
          <div class="mb-3">
            <h5>Empresa id: {{wordE.id_word}</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre de la Empresa:</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordE.name_business">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Cargo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordE.job">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Actividades o Roles:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" [(ngModel)]="wordE.chores"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Duración:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordE.duration">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Logo de la Empresa -url-:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="wordE.url_photo_business">
          </div> 
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-bs-dismiss="modal" (click)="actualizarDB()">Guardar Cambios</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el error que me muestra:

```
    Error: src/app/work-experience/work-experience.component.html:145:7 - error NG5002: Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags

145       </div>
          ~~~~~~

  src/app/work-experience/work-experience.component.ts:11:16
    11   templateUrl: './work-experience.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component WorkExperienceComponent.




× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Yo puse tu código en visual studio que marca de inmediato estos errores y solo me aparece que tienes declarado `data-bs-toggle="modal"` 2 veces en algunos elementos. Para nada con respecto al cierre de div's

Comment: Todos los `img` deberían ir con cierre en la etiqueta misma `<img src="blabla" />`, pero dudo que sea ese el problema

Comment: Mismo comentario para los `input` :)

Comment: Es una mala práctica poner más de un `id` repetido y tú tienes innumerables `id="recipient-name"`. Por cierto, el `/div` que te indica el error es el que ocupa la línea 8 contando desde el final...

Comment: mmmm también veo que en `<h5>Empresa id: {{wordE.id_word}</h5>` solo tienes una llave de cierre, aunque creo que no debería afectar, simplemente debería mostrarte la variable como texto.

Comment: Prueba a comentar todas las líneas que contienen: `<label for="recipient-name"`, y comprueba si se sigue produciendo el error, ten en cuenta que cada `for` se vincula  a un `id`, y tú, como te he dicho, tienes muchos repetidos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
</textarea [(ngModel)]="wordAdd.chores">
```

me parece que ese ngModel no va ahí.

con ctr + f puedes buscar en el código.

Comment: El ngModel iría _dentro_ de las etiquetas, ¿no? :)

Comment: como necesito mínimo 15 caracteres para responderte entonces agrego estas líneas para decirte "SI"

Comment: Gracias Javier, me sirvio de ayuda, me quito el error del cierre de etiquetas. me salto otro jaja pero es otra cosa. gracias.